# How to auto populate textbox when dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

i'm trying to auto populate text-box when drop-down is selected. I've tried some code but nothing happen i already included the jquery file in my code.

I have a database table called services and the column are service_id, service_name, service_price.

**Here's My view**

```
   <div class="form-group-inner">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-1">
   <label class="login2 pull-right pull-right-pro">Service</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="form-select-list">
   <select class="form-control custom-select-value" id="service_name" name="service_name">
   <option>Select Service</option>
   <?php foreach ($service as $services): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $services->service_id; ?>"><?php echo $services->service_name; ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group-inner">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-1">
   <label class="login2 pull-right pull-right-pro">Price</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4">
   <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control"  />
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#service_name').on('change', function() {
    var service_id=$("service_name").val();
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>/records/getprice/" + service_id,

    function(data){
    $('#price').val(data.service_price);
    });
}
<script>
```

**Controller**

```
    function add_form($patient_id){
        $data['service']=$this->services_model->get_all_services();
        $data['value'] = $this->patient_model->get_selected_patient($patient_id);
        $this->load->view('header/header');
        $this->load->view('Records/add_records',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer/footer');
    }

    function getprice($service_id){

        $laiza=$this->db->get_where("services",array("service_id"=>$service_id));
        foreach ($laiza->result() as $row){
            $arr = array('service_price' => $row->service_price);
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($arr);
        }

    }
```

I expect that when i select a data from dropdown the textbox will populate the price base on the selected item dropdown

Comment: please clarify "did not work", also what means "I expect that when i select a data from dropdown the input will" ???

Comment: `function(data){
    $('#price').val(data.service_price);
    });`

Is not valid JavaScript, function declarations need a name. Check your console for errors.

Comment: @Vickel Sorry, i already edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID selector # missing when your getting the Service_Name value

Change the same to

> var service_id=$("#service_name").val();

or

> var service_id= this.value;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#service_name').on('change', function() {
    var service_id=$("#service_name").val();
    $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>/records/getprice/" + service_id,

    function(data){
    $('#price').val(data.service_price);
    });
}
<script>
```